# What does it mean to prove that software is bugless?

Tags: correctness-proof

A computer science lecturer said that one should use test as programs can't be proved to be bugless. Is this true? What does it mean to prove that program is bugless? Is there a proof that it is impossible to find such a proof? And is there a method to transform a program to a mathematical statement whose proof can or can't be found?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Only trivial *programs* can be proven to be without bugs and even then, only in theory, not in practice. The problem is that there are too many places for a program to go wrong, many of which aren't actually part of the program itself, but, instead, part of the system(s) on which the program runs. Since a program can run essentially forever, there are an infinite number of possibilities.

It is even impossible to prove that a non trivial program even eventually halts. See [The Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), for example.

You need to distinguish, however, between programs (implementations) and algorithms (logical structures). The latter can be proven in many cases.

One can use mathematical techniques to prove the correctness of an algorithm in many cases, but not the program built from it: the implementation. A course in Data Structures and Algorithms (sometimes two courses) explores this topic.

In practice, however, one uses testing methods to show that a program meets its specification in as many important situations as can be imagined. Both pre-test ([test first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)) and post-test ([acceptance testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_testing)) techniques are used for this, but they are imperfect as (a) we don't think of everything and (b) machines themselves can be imperfect and can differ in the nature of their imperfections.

Even the physics of electronics can lead to errors in the execution of programs. We hear of new "zero-day" vulnerabilities very frequently. Some of them are caused by the fact that electronics emit various electronic fields that can be read or can interfere with various components. Such things are nearly impossible to anticipate and can't be anticipated without failure.

Comment: This answer is wrong on many levels. 1. it re-iterates the author's pet hate for verification. 2. It completely misrepresents the Halting Problem. Of course you can prove that a program must terminate. You just can't write an automatic prover that works for *all* input programs. 3. It conflates the *execution* of a program on possibly flawed hardware with its *meaning*, which hinges on a mathematical abstraction of hardware.

Comment: @Kai, hmmm, the author is something of an expert on program verification. More a lover than a hater.

Comment: I started to type up a comment here, but then I realized that I might be misinterpreting the question. When the asker says "program," are they referring to code written in a particular language? Or are they referring to (say) a compiled program, compiled by a specific compiler and running on a particular kind of hardware? In the former case, I respectfully disagree more with the answer. In the latter, I would agree with the answer a bit more. Though, in both cases I find that description of the halting problem to be somewhat misleading.

Comment: Zero-day vulnerabilities have nothing to do with bugs.

Comment: The language ADA validates the correctness of the compiler. And more generally, nothing prevents you to formally prove a program (as opposed to an algorithm ?).

Comment: @YvesDaoust, IIRC, the ADA validation is a _set of tests_ that verify that a specific compiler (an implementation) meets the standard (an algorithm, if you like).

Comment: Turing's halting problem is not even about halting. It is about provers (the exact subject of this thread). It says nothing about the ability to write a program that halts or not, or even the ability to write one that can be proved. It only discusses the ability to prove in general. However, yes modern systems are too big and complex to prove anything 100%. And, Yes don't give up: test, write clean code, static analyse, use contracts, …

Answer (score 4):

One can indeed prove algorithms and programs using techniques such as Hoare's logic. The basic idea is to establish properties linked to the current values of the variables, and check how they evolve throughout program execution. There are formal rules associated to all basic constructs of programming languages (assignment, sequence, selection, iteration). A key concept is that of invariant which, in a way, concentrates the spirit of the algorithm.

Such proofs are as robust as any mathematical proof. For a gentle introduction, read "A Method of Programming" by Edsger W. Dijkstra and W.H.J. Feijen. You will find numerous examples there.

Nowadays, proofs can be assisted by computer, using formal verification systems such as Coq.

---

Anyway, no technique can guarantee a program bug-free because

- we are humans, not fault-free cyborgs,
- a proof can be buggy as well,
- tests can be buggy as well and are always incomplete,
- specifications are often lacunary so that some behavior can be declared buggy *after the fact*.